# pandas Series functions consistency

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series of timedelta64 values:

```
>>>diff
0         NaT
1    00:10:04
2    00:10:03
3    00:11:28
.....
44   00:05:13
45   00:00:40
46   00:03:22
47   00:00:58
Name: sample_time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I wonder why mean() and std() methods returns me two different types of objects. One returns a Series object, while the other returns a generic float value (not even another timedelta64):

```
>>>diff.mean()
0   00:07:30.510638
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
>>>type(diff.mean())
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>>diff.std()
1.3312791471041715e+18
>>>type(diff.std())
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

Pandas [documentation on series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html#pandas.Series) describes the two funcion in a very similar fashion and doesn't indicates which kind of object is returned. Quoting the documentation:

> mean([axis, skipna, level, numeric_only]): Return the mean of the
>   values for the requested axis std([axis, skipna, level, ddof]) :
>   Return unbiased standard deviation over requested axis.

Comment: Not sure why this happening, but `pandas` is calling `numpy.mean,` so you could start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timedelta support in < 0.15.0 is a bit off esp for scalars. See preview of [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0150-timedeltaindex) for upcoming Timedelta support (0.15.0 releasing prob 2nd week of oct) or you can get master from GitHub.

These ops will return a Timedelta type

Comment: Shall I conclude that the behavior I describe is a bug? What do you mean by "off esp"?

Comment: well it was not implemented to a large extent before 0.15.0 because of the lack of a Timedela scalar.